# Magento 2.1 :- Update Display Error Message in Checkout Cart Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, plugin

See the below image, I want to update display error message in estimate checkout cart page with custom module.

I know that we change display error using admin-panel but i want to need custom module. I want also in checkout page.

I need to want using current customer.
I create module for Shipping Restriction, apply rule by current customer.
So i need to want change error message in cart and as well as checkout.

I use also `plugin around` for this but no one changes for that.

[image]

`Below my files are override Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping model.`

**app/code/Vendor/Shippingtest/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping" type="Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\Shipping"/>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Shippingtest_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingtest\Grid\Collection</item>                
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <virtualType name="Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingtest\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">shipping_restrict_test</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingtest</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="ShippingtestGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingtest\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">TestGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="TestGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="ShippingtestGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\Shippingtest\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingtest\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">TestGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Shippingtest/Model/Shipping.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shippingtest\Model;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Shipping implements RateCollectorInterface
{
    /**
     * Default shipping orig for requests
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_orig = null;

    /**
     * Cached result
     *
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result
     */
    protected $_result = null;

    /**
     * Part of carrier xml config path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_availabilityConfigField = 'active';

    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_shippingConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory
     */
    protected $_carrierFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequestFactory
     */
    protected $_shipmentRequestFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory
     */
    protected $_regionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Math\Division
     */
    protected $mathDivision;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $carrierFactory
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\RequestFactory $shipmentRequestFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Division $mathDivision
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $carrierFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\RequestFactory $shipmentRequestFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Division $mathDivision,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_carrierFactory = $carrierFactory;
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_shipmentRequestFactory = $shipmentRequestFactory;
        $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
        $this->mathDivision = $mathDivision;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Get shipping rate result model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        if (empty($this->_result)) {
            $this->_result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->_result;
    }

    /**
     * Set shipping orig data
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function setOrigData($data)
    {
        $this->_orig = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Reset cached result
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function resetResult()
    {
        $this->getResult()->reset();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve configuration model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->_shippingConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all methods for supplied shipping data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return $this
     * @todo make it ordered
     */
    public function collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {
        $storeId = $request->getStoreId();
        if (!$request->getOrig()) {
            $request->setCountryId(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStore()
                )
            )->setRegionId(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStore()
                )
            )->setCity(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStore()
                )
            )->setPostcode(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    Shipment::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $request->getStore()
                )
            );
        }

        $limitCarrier = $request->getLimitCarrier();
        if (!$limitCarrier) {
            $carriers = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'carriers',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $storeId
            );

            foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
                $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
            }
        } else {
            if (!is_array($limitCarrier)) {
                $limitCarrier = [$limitCarrier];
            }
            foreach ($limitCarrier as $carrierCode) {
                $carrierConfig = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'carriers/' . $carrierCode,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $storeId
                );
                if (!$carrierConfig) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Collect rates of given carrier
     *
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        /* @var $carrier \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier */
        $carrier = $this->_carrierFactory->createIfActive($carrierCode);
        if (!$carrier) {
            return $this;
        }
        $carrier->setActiveFlag($this->_availabilityConfigField);
        $result = $carrier->checkAvailableShipCountries($request);
        if (false !== $result && !$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
            $result = $carrier->proccessAdditionalValidation($request);
        }
        /*
         * Result will be false if the admin set not to show the shipping module
         * if the delivery country is not within specific countries
         */
        if (false !== $result) {
            if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
                if ($carrier->getConfigData('shipment_requesttype')) {
                    $packages = $this->composePackagesForCarrier($carrier, $request);
                    if (!empty($packages)) {
                        $sumResults = [];
                        foreach ($packages as $weight => $packageCount) {
                            $request->setPackageWeight($weight);
                            $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                            if (!$result) {
                                return $this;
                            } else {
                                $result->updateRatePrice($packageCount);
                            }
                            $sumResults[] = $result;
                        }
                        if (!empty($sumResults) && count($sumResults) > 1) {
                            $result = [];
                            foreach ($sumResults as $res) {
                                if (empty($result)) {
                                    $result = $res;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                foreach ($res->getAllRates() as $method) {
                                    foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $resultMethod) {
                                        if ($method->getMethod() == $resultMethod->getMethod()) {
                                            $resultMethod->setPrice($method->getPrice() + $resultMethod->getPrice());
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                }
                if (!$result) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
            if ($carrier->getConfigData('showmethod') == 0 && $result->getError()) {
                return $this;
            }
            // sort rates by price
            if (method_exists($result, 'sortRatesByPrice') && is_callable([$result, 'sortRatesByPrice'])) {
                $result->sortRatesByPrice();
            }
            $this->getResult()->append($result);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Compose Packages For Carrier.
     * Divides order into items and items into parts if it's necessary
     *
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier $carrier
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return array [int, float]
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function composePackagesForCarrier($carrier, $request)
    {
        $allItems = $request->getAllItems();
        $fullItems = [];

        $maxWeight = (double)$carrier->getConfigData('max_package_weight');

        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE
                && $item->getProduct()->getShipmentType()
            ) {
                continue;
            }

            $qty = $item->getQty();
            $changeQty = true;
            $checkWeight = true;
            $decimalItems = [];

            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                if (!$item->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getShipmentType()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $qty = $item->getIsQtyDecimal()
                    ? $item->getParentItem()->getQty()
                    : $item->getParentItem()->getQty() * $item->getQty();
            }

            $itemWeight = $item->getWeight();
            if ($item->getIsQtyDecimal()
                && $item->getProductType() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE
            ) {
                $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();

                $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId, $item->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                if ($stockItem->getIsDecimalDivided()) {
                    if ($stockItem->getEnableQtyIncrements() && $stockItem->getQtyIncrements()) {
                        $itemWeight = $itemWeight * $stockItem->getQtyIncrements();
                        $qty = round($item->getWeight() / $itemWeight * $qty);
                        $changeQty = false;
                    } else {
                        $itemWeight = $itemWeight * $item->getQty();
                        if ($itemWeight > $maxWeight) {
                            $qtyItem = floor($itemWeight / $maxWeight);
                            $decimalItems[] = ['weight' => $maxWeight, 'qty' => $qtyItem];
                            $weightItem = $this->mathDivision->getExactDivision($itemWeight, $maxWeight);
                            if ($weightItem) {
                                $decimalItems[] = ['weight' => $weightItem, 'qty' => 1];
                            }
                            $checkWeight = false;
                        } else {
                            $itemWeight = $itemWeight * $item->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $itemWeight = $itemWeight * $item->getQty();
                }
            }

            if ($checkWeight && $maxWeight && $itemWeight > $maxWeight) {
                return [];
            }

            if ($changeQty
                && !$item->getParentItem()
                && $item->getIsQtyDecimal()
                && $item->getProductType() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE
            ) {
                $qty = 1;
            }

            if (!empty($decimalItems)) {
                foreach ($decimalItems as $decimalItem) {
                    $fullItems = array_merge(
                        $fullItems,
                        array_fill(0, $decimalItem['qty'] * $qty, $decimalItem['weight'])
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $fullItems = array_merge($fullItems, array_fill(0, $qty, $itemWeight));
            }
        }
        sort($fullItems);

        return $this->_makePieces($fullItems, $maxWeight);
    }

    /**
     * Make pieces
     * Compose packages list based on given items, so that each package is as heavy as possible
     *
     * @param array $items
     * @param float $maxWeight
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _makePieces($items, $maxWeight)
    {
        $pieces = [];
        if (!empty($items)) {
            $sumWeight = 0;

            $reverseOrderItems = $items;
            arsort($reverseOrderItems);

            foreach ($reverseOrderItems as $key => $weight) {
                if (!isset($items[$key])) {
                    continue;
                }
                unset($items[$key]);
                $sumWeight = $weight;
                foreach ($items as $key => $weight) {
                    if ($sumWeight + $weight < $maxWeight) {
                        unset($items[$key]);
                        $sumWeight += $weight;
                    } elseif ($sumWeight + $weight > $maxWeight) {
                        $pieces[] = (string)(double)$sumWeight;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        unset($items[$key]);
                        $pieces[] = (string)(double)($sumWeight + $weight);
                        $sumWeight = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($sumWeight > 0) {
                $pieces[] = (string)(double)$sumWeight;
            }
            $pieces = array_count_values($pieces);
        }

        return $pieces;
    }

    /**
     * Collect rates by address
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $address
     * @param null|bool|array $limitCarrier
     * @return $this
     */
    public function collectRatesByAddress(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $address, $limitCarrier = null)
    {
        /** @var $request \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest */
        $request = $this->_shipmentRequestFactory->create();
        $request->setAllItems($address->getAllItems());
        $request->setDestCountryId($address->getCountryId());
        $request->setDestRegionId($address->getRegionId());
        $request->setDestPostcode($address->getPostcode());
        $request->setPackageValue($address->getBaseSubtotal());
        $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount());
        $request->setPackageWeight($address->getWeight());
        $request->setFreeMethodWeight($address->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($address->getItemQty());
        $request->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $request->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $request->setBaseCurrency($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency());
        $request->setPackageCurrency($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency());
        $request->setLimitCarrier($limitCarrier);

        $request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($address->getBaseSubtotalInclTax());

        return $this->collectRates($request);
    }

    /**
     * Set part of carrier xml config path
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCarrierAvailabilityConfigField($code = 'active')
    {
        $this->_availabilityConfigField = $code;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

How it possible? Please give me suggetion.

Comment: Please provide more details: What exactly do you want the custom module to do? Updating the configuration for a specific shipping method? For all shipping methods? To a dynamic text or a static text? Only in the shipping estimation or in the checkout as well?

Comment: Hello, check my updated question.

Comment: I create module shipping restriction apply rule by current customer.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to restrict shipping via customer so we can help

Comment: Ok, I post my code in few minutes.

Comment: Hello everyone, please give me answer for this question.

Comment: @PayalPatel  are you find any solution for this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a block file in your module for this.

And Create a file in `app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/file.phtml`

In this file you can get the customer session and quote data. So that you can perform any calculation based on that.

To call this block in checkout and cart page you have to define both xml file for that in the same module ie.

```
checkout_index_index.xml

checkout_cart_index.xml
```

In these xml you can call your block file with the help of refrence.

Comment: Hey Ashish, i know for that but i think this is not possible in this way. Because ko template use in shipping.phtml and onepage.phtml file.

Answer (score -2):

Go To **Store-> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods**.
Select shipping method for which you want to edit message.
There is a field with "**Displayed Error Message**", add your custom message which you want to show.

Comment: Hello MageComp, Thanks for your reply, but I already mention that using custom module. And your answer is not useful for this. Please give me suggestion using custom module.

Comment: Custom module means you have created custom shipping method and you need to implement this functionality into that extension same like default shipping method.

Comment: Yes MageComp you are right.