# Magento 2.1:- Create Plugin but not working in custom module

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento-2.1, plugin

I create plugin in my custom module to override the method `collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)`, below code is not working.
What mistake here?

**app/code/Vendor/Shippingtest/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin name="vendor-shippingtest-test"
                type="Vendor\Shippingtest\Plugin\Test"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Shippingtest/Plugin/Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shippingtest\Plugin;

class Test
{
    public function after(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, $result)
    {
        echo "Calling";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but there's a major problem in your method name, **it does not contain the name of the original method**.

You should replace:

```
public function after(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, $result)
```

With:

```
public function afterCollectCarrierRates(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, $result)
```

So your plugin can work.

Comment: Hello Raphael,thanks to reply. I try to use your code, but same here plugin is not working.

Comment: @PayalPatel I'm not sure an echo would be enough to show your the code is working. Try to log data by using the following method http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method

Comment: Try to log data but log file is not create in var/log folder.

Comment: @PayalPatel How are you testing your module ? Are you sure you follow a testing procedure that triggers the original `collectCarrierRates` method ?

Comment: Ya i am sure for `collectCarrierRates` method. I try to update display error message in **checkout/cart/ page**. I already ask question previously. But no any answer get here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134461/magento-2-1-update-display-error-message-in-checkout-cart-page

Comment: @PayalPatel maybe try to move your `di.xml` outside the frontend folder